# androidviewclient: store view client dumps

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

Is there some way to store dumps in a dictionary and use these dumps at a later time so that the dump does not have to be recalculated every time? This is a more a proof of concept question as I'm looking for a way to speed up androidviewclient's slow dump process and make my script quicker in any manner. For instance, AVC returns to the home-screen between my script's steps but needs to dump again before refinding the (u'''Applications''') button a few times.

This is problematic as it creates unnecessary wait times as my script is trying to configure the device's settings as quickly as possible and launch apps. I would like to create the home-screen dump once, store it, and refer back to that dump that I stored to click the (u'''Applications''') button between steps, or have some alternative method of creating a faster script. If this isn't possible, I would like to know what other script writing software works more quickly than AVC without sacrificing effectiveness as I do like the consistency with find views/buttons, and rewriting my functional yet slow script is no problem.

So far I have searched, found nothing, and tried the following after looking through viewclient.py:

```
dictDump = {}
home() #helper method that goes to the home screen
dictDump['homeScreen'] = vc.dump()
vc.findViewWithContentDescription(u'''Applications''').touch()
dictDump['appScreen'] = vc.dump()
home()
vc.views = dictDump['homeScreen']
vc.findViewWithContentDescription(u'''Applications''').touch()
```

And I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'touch'

Answer (score 0):

This is a `culebra` generated script slightly modified to do what you are asking for.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2016  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-06-21 by Culebra v11.5.9
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)


device.press('HOME')
vc.dump(window=-1)
# let's keep the reference to apps (dangerous but possible)
apps = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''Apps''')

apps.touch()

vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)

vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''API Demos''').touch()

device.press('HOME')

# use the reference we kept
apps.touch()

vc.dump(window=-1)

browser = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''Browser''')
browser.touch()

device.press('HOME')
```

The script keeps the reference to **apps** and reuse it.
Keeping the reference may not work in many other situations but because it's very unlikely the the home screen or the **Apps** button change you may be fine.

Comment: In order to find view, Do we need to always call `dump` method?

Comment: `dump` has to be invoked every time the Views change